# Loop through and submit multiple forms without reloading page using javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms

I have a page of around 40 forms that all need submitted when the "Save All" button is pressed. The problem is that when I try and loop through the forms and submit them only the first form gets submitted. How would I refactor this so that all the forms on the page get submitted? I realize this question has been asked before and that the likely solution has to do with AJAX but I'm just not sure how to implement such a thing.

The Javascript I have so far looks like this:

```
function SaveAllForms() {
    document.getElementById("SaveAll").innerText = "Processing..";
    var forms = document.forms;
    for (var f = 0, fLen = forms.length; f < fLen; f++) {
        var form = forms[f];
        form.submit();
    }
    window.location.reload();
}
```

And all the forms look something like this. I'm only including one because like I said, there are around 40 of them on the page:

```
<form action="/FormSubmitLocation" method="post" name="Feed3">    <tr>

    <td>
        <input type="hidden" name="PREcost" value="3.027" />
        <input type="hidden" name="PREtaxadd" value="4.5" />
        1         
        <input id="Zone" name="Zone" type="hidden" value="1         " />
    </td>
    <td>
        SomeZone
        <input id="ZoneDescription" name="ZoneDescription" type="hidden" value="SomeZone" />
    </td>
    <td>
        SomeCity
        <input id="Rack" name="Rack" type="hidden" value="SomeCity" />
    </td>
    <td>
        SomeProduct
        <input id="ActualProduct" name="ActualProduct" type="hidden" value="SomeProduct" />
    </td>
    <td>
        3.027
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Cost must be a number." id="Cost" name="Cost" type="hidden" value="3.027" />
    </td>
    <td>
        0.69
        <input id="Tax" name="Tax" type="hidden" value="0.686488  " />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field DMarkup must be a number." id="DMarkup" name="DMarkup" onchange="calcNewMarkup(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;);" onfocus="javascript:if (this.value!=&#39;&#39;){calcNewMarkup(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;)};" style="width: 70px;" type="text" value="69.58" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input Class="PREDretail form-control" id="DSell" name="DSell" onchange="calcNewMargin(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;);" style="width: 70px;" type="text" value="3.859     " />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RMarkup must be a number." id="RMarkup" name="RMarkup" onchange="calcNewMarkupRemote(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;);" onfocus="javascript:if (this.value!=&#39;&#39;){calcNewMarkupRemote(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;)};" style="width: 70px;" type="text" value="69.67" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input Class="PRERretail form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field RSell must be a number." id="RSell" name="RSell" onchange="calcNewMarginRemote(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;);" onfocus="javascript:if (this.value!=&#39;&#39;){calcNewMarginRemote(this.value,&#39;PRE&#39;,&#39;Feed3&#39;)};" style="width: 70px;" type="text" value="3.8599" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <small id="Update3">3/1/2020 7:57:00 PM</small>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field DateUpdated must be a date." id="DateUpdated" name="DateUpdated" type="hidden" value="3/1/2020 7:57:00 PM" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field cpid must be a number." data-val-required="The cpid field is required." id="cpid" name="cpid" type="hidden" value="641" />
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field orpid must be a number." data-val-required="The orpid field is required." id="orpid" name="orpid" type="hidden" value="6" />
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="Feed3">Update</button>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Any examples of how to get this to work would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you dont even need forms for ajax requests... its an old way to send data.

Anyway you should prevent the default behaviour of the forms:

```
form.preventDefault();
```

Comment: I placed this prior to the form.submit() and it just seems to hang at "Processing..".

Comment: Nevermind. form.submit().preventDefault() seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can submit forms with a target, including iframes.  You don't need JavaScript to do this outside of invoking submit() as you are. For example

```
<form target="iframe1_name" ...> ... </form>
<iframe name="iframe1_name" src="about:blank" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

You can repeat this as often as you want, each form will submit to their hidden iframe.

https://jsfiddle.net/efdmsao8/

Side Note:  you may want to avoid calling that reload as it would cancel any pending submits, or wrap it in a timeout to allow them to finish before it

Comment: Seems to add an unnecessary amount of clutter to the page instead of just preventing the default behavior.